# Is it possible to do cross-platform websocket code in Xamarin?

Tags: websocket, xamarin

I am looking to build an iOS/Android app that uses a client websocket.  Is it possible to do this within a "unified project?".

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebSocket4Net cannot Nuget dependency to iOS project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814278/websocket4net-cannot-nuget-dependency-to-ios-project)

Comment: I would take a look at https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl